# introducir input de párrafo en php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[image: codigo php][[image: codigo][1]]   Quisiera añadirle un párrafo o un input para introducir un parafo en ello.

```
<?php 
   required 'dbc.php';
   if (isset($_POST['btn_upload'])){
       $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"];
       $filename  = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"];
       $filetype  = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"];
       $filepath  = "img/" . $filename;
       $filetitle = $_POST['img_title'];
       move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);
       $stmt = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_photos (img_name, img_type, img_path, img_title) VALUES (:iname, :itype, :ipath, :ititle) ");
       $stmt->bindValue(':iname', $filename);
       $stmt->bindValue('itype', $filetype);
       $stmt->bindValue('ipath', $filepath);
       $stmt->bindValue('ititle', $filetitle);
       if ($stmt->execute()) {
           header('Location: index.php?success=yes&title=' . $filetitle);
        }else{
            header('Location: index.php?success=no');
        }  
    }
?>
```

Para mostrar

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['success'])) {
        if($_GET['success']=="yes"){
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
            <div data-alert class="alert-box success radius ">
                Image "<?= $_GET['title']; ?>" uploaded successfully.
                <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
            <div data-alert class="alert-box alert radius ">There was a problem uploading the image.<a href="#" class="close">&times;</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Estoy haciendo un crud php mysql. la parte required es para los campos input (html). Lo que quiero es agregar un nuevo input o área de texto para poder agregar un párrafo. Tengo ya el título y la parte del párrafo quisiera mostrarla también la forma en la que muestro también el título.

Comment: ¿Podrías darle algo de formato al código? Se hace difícil leer así como está. Por otra parte veo que usas "required", eso no es código php... ¿esto que escribiste funciona? Tampoco me queda muy clara la idea de lo que quieres lograr... ¿podrías ponerlo más explícitamente?

Comment: puedes colocar el codigo identado por favor... hacer scroll horizontal mas de 120 caracteres me da jaqueca y se sale del estandar PSR XD